# Can one be inflicted with the same poison several times?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, poison

If I am a volley-archer, and all my arrows are coated in the same poison- Could I infect one target with that poison more than once in one round?

For instance:
All my arrows are coated with poison that deals 1D6 dex damage. Its secondary damage is another 1D6 dex. 
On my first hit, my target fails his save. Does he still need to make saves for the other arrows that hit him, or will he not be able to take more damage from the poison until he has made or failed the save for the secondary damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Rules Compendium* says

> Each instance of poisoning damages a poisoned creature separately. In the case of poisons that have nondamaging effects, those effects don’t stack, but each one runs for its full duration. (109)

Thus, in the archer's case, all of the poisoned arrows will attempt to deal their poison damage normally even if the poison is the same kind.